# Can we pass a JSON object directly to another route through Vue router without using JSON.stringify

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When I initially tried to pass the object which is an array of other objects (received from an axios post) to another route like this:

```
this.$router.push({
    name: "EMR",
    params: {
        records: response,
    },
});
```

I received an array like the following:

```
[Object Object],
[Object Object],
...
[Object Object]
```

I could fix it using:

```
this.$router.push({
    name: "EMR",
    params: {
        records: JSON.stringify(response),
    },
});
```

And then using the following in the destination route:

```
created () {    
    this.clinical_records = JSON.parse(this.$route.params.records)   
}
```

Is this the proper way to do this? Or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the data as prop via vue-router: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#object-mode

**EDIT**

Example:

In your route configuration, you activate passing params as props:

```
routes: [
  {
    name: "EMR",
    path: "your/path/to/emr"
    props: {
      default: true,
    },
  },
  // other routes...
]
```

In the target component, you declare your prop:

```
props: {
  clinical_records: Array,
}
```

Then you will be able to use directly:

```
this.$router.push({
    name: "EMR",
    params: {
        clinical_records: response,
    },
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I still got a similiar array when I added these props